# Can Onmouseover be used outside a Hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to build onmouseover directly into a javascript block. I can do it within a hyperlink but I need to do it in the actual script section for the code im writing. Can I do object.onMouseOver()? Or is there another way to do it?
So for example I'd like

```
<script>
something i can put in here that will make on mouseover work on a specific object
</script>
```

Comment: what.................?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. :)

```
<span onmouseover="alert('Hi there')">Hi there</span>
```

Do you mean like that?

edited to add:

Ah I see so like this?

```
<span id="span1">Hi there</span>

<script>
    document.getElementById('span1').onmouseover  = function() {
        alert('Hi there');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You bind events to HTML elements not `javascript` blocks. If you are talking about binding events to elements using script, yes you can do it. You can use `addEventListener` to bind events.

```
document.getElementById("eleid").addEventListener("mouseOver", myEventMethod, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can so if you have a link somewhere in the page that you want to fire the hover for you can use the following.

http://jsbin.com/asoma4/edit

EDIT: I should add that the attached is just an ugly example to demonstrate that what you want to do can be done. I would look into popular js libraries (jquery, prototype, etc..) to clean this up a lot and make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addEventListener` in Firefox/Chrome/etc. and `attachEvent` in IE. See [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).

For example,

```
<div id="cool">Click here!</div>
<script>
    function divClicked()
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }

    var theDiv = document.getElementById("cool");
    if(theDiv.attachEvent)
    {
        // IE
        theDiv.attachEvent('onclick', divClicked);
    }
    else
    {
        // Other browsers
        theDiv.addEventListener('click', divClicked, false);
    }
</script>
```

If you want to avoid having to write all that code, you can use a JavaScript library ([jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), etc.) to simply your code.